# How to copy the last data column and insert it immediately to the right?

Tags: excel, vba, insertion

I have this data
[image]

This code grabs column "BO" and copies it to the right.

I need a repeatable macro that copies column BK and inserts it to the right, which pushes the blank space & totals over. I am putting this on a button so I can repeat the add column.

```vb
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
  xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column
ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)

End Sub
```

This looks like it'll do the job.

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim LastCol As Integer

Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
  xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

LastCol = rLastCell.Column ws.Columns(LastCol - 4).Copy
ws.Columns(LastCol - 3).Insert shift:=xlToRight

End Sub
```

Comment: Why duplicate data? surely 1 copy is sufficient?

Comment: Use `Range.Insert`?

Comment: Each column represents an active week.  Every week I'll need to add a new column thereby extending the size of the data range.  The issue is that I need to keep the three totals columns at the end.  I thought I would separate the totals from the data with a blank column.  My current formulas are written to include the new column as they are added so that part is not an issue.

Comment: This looks like it'll do the job....  Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim LastCol As Integer

    Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    LastCol = rLastCell.Column

    ws.Columns(LastCol - 4).Copy
    ws.Columns(LastCol - 3).Insert shift:=xlToRight

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is much more simple than what you have!
Look at the needed code

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet,rLastCell as range, LastCol as long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _ xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False) 
LastCol = rLastCell.Column

ws.Columns(LastCol-3).copy 
ws.Columns(LastCol-2).insert shift:=xlToRigh

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem I have is that I'll need to repeatedly add a new column by copying the previous column that has formulas already in it that reference new data points from other worksheets, not simply adding a blank column. As the macro write a new column, the next time it will need to grab that "New" last data column and recopy it (Insert) immediately to the right which will expand my data.

Comment: So you want to keep the last 3 columns intact and add one column at the end of data? Then try (in your original code) to change the line :
ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy ws.Columns(LastCol + 1)  with these two (as in my code): ws.Columns(LastCol-3).copy
ws.Columns(LastCol-2).insert shift:=xlToRight

Comment: Excellent!!   Thank you.  This looks like it works                 Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim LastCol As Integer

    Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    LastCol = rLastCell.Column

    ws.Columns(LastCol - 4).Copy
    ws.Columns(LastCol - 3).Insert shift:=xlToRight

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the request is, that Jeff wants to copy the column he thinks, it's the last one immediately right to it.

But the problem is, that often Excel considers a different column as last one than the user: If a cell e.g. contains a formula where the result is nothing, the cell is empty for the user, but not for Excel. So it's not so easy to figure out the last column.

One workaround I would suggest is: Select a cell in the column you think, it's the last one, start the macro that copies the selected column right to it:

```
Sub CopyColumnToTheRight()

Dim ThisCol As Integer, ThisRow As Long, CurS As Worksheet, IsOk As Boolean

Set CurS = ActiveSheet
ThisRow = ActiveCell.Row
ThisCol = ActiveCell.Column

IsOk = IsEmpty(CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + 1))
If IsOk Then 'just to prevent to start the macro on the wrong column
   CurS.Columns(ThisCol).Copy
   CurS.Columns(ThisCol + 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
   CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + 1).Select
Else
   Beep
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I completely remove the totals then my macro will work repeatedly, however I really need to keep the totals columns if possible

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it was not clear to me that you have 3 more columns to the right.

The 'IsOk' simply checks, if the cell right of the selected is empty to avoid to run this macro in the wrong column.
If you replace it with

```
IsOk = IsEmpty(CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + 4))
```

it checks, if the cell in the column 4 more right (after your 3 summary columns) is blank.

```
IsOk = CurS.Cells(ThisRow, ThisCol + 1).HasFormula
```

checks, if the cell right of you has a formula. This version will also work, if you add more columns with formulas to the right

```
IsOk = True
```

Disables this feature, you can insert the new column all over the entire sheet.